# checking whether a form value has changed upon submit

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I'm creating a web app with Codeigniter, and I've created some edit forms (which pull current values from a mysql database). The user can edit the current database data by editing the data in the form.

What I want to do is perform certain actions if the user changes certain values. So, I don't just want to perform the action when a field has a certain value, but only at the point when the user changes the value and submits the form. (Specifically, when the user indicates that she's performed a certain task by changing a value from "no" to "yes", then I want to do things like set a timestamp for the completion of the task, etc.)

I've tried googling a solution, but I'm having trouble finding what I need. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't used CodeIgniter, but I've certainly done what you're doing in pure PHP-based sites.

I've followed two ways of thinking, in different projects.

**Strategy #1: Multiple writes are cheap.**

If a user clicks "Submit" rather than "Cancel", they've changed at least one field.  So the cost of doing an `UPDATE table SET name=%s,email=%s,gender=%s WHERE id=%d` isn't much more than a simple `UPDATE table SET gender=%s WHERE id=%d`.  If you're going to the expense of a WHERE and a write, making the write a few extra fields doesn't matter, especially with the frequency that it'll happen.

So: don't worry about it, just update everything with what you get back in the form.  If you overwrite a field with the same data, it doesn't matter.  When it comes down to it, you want your database to reflect everything that came back in the form, regardless of what was in the db before.

**Strategy #2: Use a session variable.**

If you've populated the form with current data, you've already likely pulled it into an array.  So copy the array into `$_SESSION`, and compare the fields after the POST.

Strategy 1 is easier to program, but *does* use slightly more database CPU and bandwidth. Strategy 2 is has slightly less database impact at the expense of quite a bit more CPU used on your web server, and it's more prone to development error.

I still don't know which way is better, but the arguments for both seem valid. These days, I tend to go for whatever solution is the most simple. But I realize that it's easier to scale your web cluster than your database cluster, so if you're developing something that will be very large, it's probably better to put more effort into optimizing things in favour of your database rather than your web servers.

Note that if you're storing your session data in a database instead of temp files, then #2 is actually *more* costly in terms of database server impact.

Comment: Okay, reading over these suggestions, I think I can do what I need to do within the form processing controller in Codeigniter: I have to pull all of the posted data into an array within the controller anyway (prior to updating the database). I could just pull the current data from the database into the controller as well (as a separate array?) and then just compare the relevant key values between the two arrays.

Comment: Yup, that sounds CodeIgniterly equivalent to my strategy #2.  Do keep in mind what you're optimizing, though.  If your sessions are backed by your DB, you'll actually be *increasing* load across the board with this method rather than decreasing it.

Answer (score 1):

You're saying that the users can edit entries from a database, so just send the record `id` as a hidden input field.

By the time the user submits the form, you retrieve the database record using the hidden field and make the necessary comparisons.

Btw, to prevent users from trying to modify other's records it's advisable to add a checksum to the `id` field that only you can verify, something that can be done using [`hash_hmac`](http://au.php.net/hash_hmac). Alternatively, you could verify the record ownership if they're logged in.

Comment: one word of advice is to make sure XSS filtering is used to make sure the form cant be mucked with.

Comment: @Mike the more immediate concern that came to mind is the use of unsigned id fields, for which I've updated the question; thanks for the comment though, XSS filtering should always be done of course :)

Comment: Or instead of a checksum for the ID field, you use an ACL and/or have a column to indicate row ownership.

Comment: @damianb agreed; that would be another consideration

Answer (score 0):

The only real solution here is knowing the initial value of the form input and then comparing it to the submitted value. You *could* pass the original value to the browser as a hidden form field and a slightly different name and then compare the two server-side though -- that should net you the desired effect if you don't know what the original value is already.

Comment: Relying on the browser to provide authoritative/important information is a very bad idea.  Rule #1 of web application security: don't trust anything you get from the client.

Comment: @ghoti - in this circumstance it's irrelevant. The only thing that can happen in this instance is that an update *won't* be triggered when it might have been.